Handle new line (\n) in SpannableString or Html.fromHtml
I have a text view. When I simply set its text a string containing \n , it works fine and automatically goes to the next line, but as I want to format the text, (for example format the color of hashtags or mentions with atsigns) I tried to user Html.fromHtml or SpannableStrings but neither of them handle these linebreaks with \n s and I don't know how to show the linebreaks correctly.
fun formatHypertext(simpleText: String, textView: TextView) {
    val spannable = SpannableString(simpleText)
    textView.text = spannable
}

There is a bad idea to dynamically recognize \n s and  separate the lines and create as many as needed text views programmatically , but that seems a bad idea. Is there any better way to handle this?
In Html.fromHtml I tried to replace the \\n s with <br> or <br/> or even \\n\\n (two instead of one) but it didn't work so I moved into using of SpannableString but it didn't work either.
In Html.fromHtml also I tried to replace the new lines with <p>/*each line*/</p> but it showd a large distance between the lines (acturally paragraphs) so I tried to set style and margin for the <p> tags but it didn't applied.
I also have tried HtmlCompat.fromHtml and it had the same problem.

How is it handling linebreaks and how did you want it to handle linebreaks?

I want it to go to the next line as it should do but it just ignores the \n (and in html.fromHtml, ignores  as well). for example if the original text is "first line \n second line" it simple shows "first line  second line"

The first thing I would do is look at the output of fromHtml and see if the \n is still there or not.  If it is there, then the problem isn't fromHtml, it's the textview.  I would actually be really surprised if that function was stripping the \n
